# Chaining CFWindow does not work as expected

Tags: coldfusion

I am new to ColdFusion but I received a project to create a web app.

I am stuck at making multiple cfwindow's. I have a page that displays all upcoming training classes (called page A). It allows an admin to click on a link to open a window and view  all students registered for that class (called page B). In page B, I would like to have a link under each students name. When the instructor clicks on it, he can open another `cfwindow` containing a form for entering payment information. ie Check number sent by the student.

Here is what I've got so far:

**Page A:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function viewList(id)
{
        try {
            ColdFusion.Window.destroy('view', true);
        }catch(e) {}
        ColdFusion.Window.create('view','Registration List', 'registration_list.cfm?id=' + id, {center:true, width:300, height:100, model:true});
}
</script>
<!---output trainingid with a given query name--->
<cfoutput query="myqueryname">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center"><a href="##" onclick="javascript:viewList('#TrainingID#')">View Registration List</a></td>
</tr>
</cfoutput>

<cfajaximport tags = "cfwindow">
<cfajaximport tags = "cfform">
```

**Page B:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDetail(detailid)
{
    try {
            ColdFusion.Window.destroy('viewFull', true);
        }catch(e) {}
        ColdFusion.Window.create('viewFull','Detail List', 'detail_form.cfm', {center:true, width:300, height:100, modal:false});       
}
</script>

<cfoutput query="viewregistration">
First Name:#viewregistration.FirstName#<br />
Last Name: #viewregistration.LastName#<br />
Email: #viewregistration.Email# <br />
County: #viewregistration.Name#<br />
<a href="##" onclick="javascript:showDetail('#ContactID#');">View</a>
</cfoutput>
<cfajaximport tags = "cfwindow">
<cfajaximport tags = "cfform">
```

When I test my page and click on "View", nothing shows up. However, when I change `onclick` to display an `alert()`, it does work. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This propably isn't related to your problem, but on page A you've said `model:true` instead of `modal:true`

Comment: All of the javascript functions belong inside the main page. ie Move the `showDetail` function to "Page A".

Comment: As an aside, if you are not already using them - take a look at the [CF Ajax debugger](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=ajaxdata_10.html) and the [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) plugin. They make troubleshooting a lot easier than alerts ;-)

Comment: @duncan: Ohh, it was a typo, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Couple of things that I notice; in page B you are not passing the `detailid` to your `detail_form.cfm` page. Page A is opening Page B in a modal window.  Then page B is trying to open another window, not sure what affect that will have since, by definition, a modal window will keep focus until you close it.  Try changing to non-modal windows and see if that helps. If that is the issue then you can work out how you want to handle them.

Comment: Miguel: Thanks for the feedback, but moving all the function to the main page fix my problem. However I noticed working with multiple cfwindows cause me too much problems after submitting form inside a cfwindow so I may have to think of another way.